# What is the best way to get information to display in detail page in flutter?

Tags: flutter, routes, flutter-web, navigator

Usually we have 2 kind of widgets to represent entities of any kind - one is the widget to display list of entities (it uses less information received from API), second is a widget to display entity detail (it uses more information received from API). The *listing widget* usually uses `StreamBuilder` which generates a `ListView`. Tapping on required `ListTile` user is navigated to *detail widget*.

The question is where to request entity details (i.e. request to API /entities/:id) in *listing widget* or in *detail widget*? I.e. there are two ways to declare detail widget class contructor:

```dart
class EntityDetail extends ... {
  EntityDetail(this.entity);
  final Entity entity;
}
```

or

```dart
class EntityDetail extends ... {
  EntityDetail(this.entityId);
  final int entityId;
}
```

The question is raised while I was investigating Navigator 2.0 (especially in web) when deep-linking is possible.

Comment: If you plan on using deep-linking the optimal solution would be to use ids, and fetch the data in from the api.

Comment: @Andrej, do you mean use second example of widget and request API from detail, not from list?

Comment: Yes. Pass the id into the detail screen and call api from there.